# How to call a Query other than by name in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I know it is possible to call query by name as follow:

```
DoCmd.OpenQuery "yourQueryName", acViewNormal, acEdit
```

OR

```
CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("yourQueryName")
```

But is it possible to call them with numbers like Sheets in Excel? 
Something like:

```
CurrentDb.OpenRecordset Queries(1)
```

or any other way possible?
Note: I want to do that because my queries are in Japanese and I would like to avoid the hard way to read them in VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly execute queries using the `QueryDefs` collection. However, referring to them by position is a dangerous thing to do, since the position may change and you might be opening the wrong query.

To do so, you can use `CurrentDb.QueryDefs(1).OpenRecordset`

Note that Access also makes temporary/internal queries available to the `QueryDefs` collection. Their name starts with `~`, and there are often many on a large database.

<sub>(in my general development database, the first real query is currently `QueryDefs(20)`)</sub>

Comment: i think you mean `QueryDefs` *collection*. ; )